# how to catch NoRouteToHostException

Tags: java, exception

I am assign to make a method to check if the internet is reachable or not.
So I try this dummy method to return false if connection is not possible.

```
 public static boolean isInternetReachable()
 {
     try {
         //make a URL to a known source
         URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

         //open a connection to that source
         HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

         //trying to retrieve data from the source. If there
         //is no connection, this line will fail
         urlConnect.setConnectTimeout(1000);
         Object objData = urlConnect.getContent();

     } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     }

     catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     } 
     catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

However, I got this error instead of catching a exception (and be able to return false)

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(Unknown Source)
at log2.isInternetReachable(log2.java:59)
at log2$7.actionPerformed(log2.java:319)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And I can't just use catch (NoRouteToHostException e) to catch the exception.
How can I correctly return false if connection is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch it similarly as you are catching other exceptions.

[#NoRouteToHostException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html)

Moreover if you can use `Exception` only which is super class of all exceptions which can catch any `Exception` (*Father of all Exception*).

```
try
{
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

OR

```
try
    {
    }
    catch(NoRouteToHostException e){}
```

*One more thing you are catching one by one Exceptions rather you can put one try and use multiple catches if you want to.*

**Moreover you are only catching `IOException` so other exceptions will not be caught.**

Comment: sorry but the error still occur no matter how much exception I put in

Comment: I try to pack all code to one try and it didn't help.

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` will print the exception stack check whether you are passing the correct route or not

Comment: so I should remove them?

Comment: No Not at all they will navigate you for the source from where the Exception occured please go for line number 59 and 102 which is generating exception and solve the problem.I guide you for your question you asked ...If you want to know why this exception is being generated you can ask another question. :0

Comment: ok Thank you. Actually it guide me the the line I call this method and the urlConnect.getContent();